# How to update the whole collection using mongoose and nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have a collection of drafts;
and I simply got everything with

```
let drafts = await Drafts.find();
```

now, I created new documents for this collection and I want to replace the old documents with the new ones

I tried `await drafts.updateMany(newDrafts)`  but it didn't work and I can't find anything on google.

```
drafts = newDrafts;
await drafts.save()
```

didn't work either

Comment: Is there any error? What result did you expect? Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: there is no error, it just doesn't update the whole collection. So I get from the database document1, document2, and document3. I want to change them with document4, document5, document6